# How functions executed declared inside class declaration in c++?

Tags: c++

Some code contains function invoked inside class declaration.

```
class Example
{
   public:
    bool keyBlobClosed = deviceClosed()?true:false;
};
```

In this case, deviceClosed() function gets executed when object created or when class declaration created in memory?

Answer (score 2):

This is called a [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization). It is allowed on non-static members (as you have used here) since C++11.

It is equivalent to providing a member initializer list that performs the same initialization:

```
class Example {
public:
    bool keyBlobClosed;
    Example() 
        : keyBlobClosed(deviceClosed())
    {
    }
};
```

Obviously, this will cause deviceClosed() to be called whenever Example is instantiated. The return value of deviceClosed() will be used to initialize keyBlobClosed.

Comment: It means that, I can't use "default member initializer" for abstract class?

Comment: Yes, a default member initializer is allowed for an abstract class.